# Modules in /proc/modules address issue

Tags: drivers, kernel, proc

If I cat of the /proc/modules the RAM address location of modules is always 0x0000000000000000.

Any ideas?

```
vmnet 51316 13 - Live 0x0000000000000000 (OX)
parport_pc 32701 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000
vmw_vsock_vmci_transport 26278 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000
vsock 34903 1 vmw_vsock_vmci_transport, Live 0x0000000000000000
vmw_vmci 62966 1 vmw_vsock_vmci_transport, Live 0x0000000000000000
vmmon 80278 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000 (OX)
bnep 19624 2 - Live 0x0000000000000000
rfcomm 69160 0 - Live 0x0000000000000000
...
```

Comment: anyone? something?

Comment: As the answer below says, use: `sudo cat /proc/modules` to see real addresses.

Answer (score 3):

add sudo, only priviledge user can see the details.

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to look at `kptr_restrict` file. It was created specifically to hide address information given in `/proc`.
The solution was to

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/kptr_restrict
```

More information here

https://sysctl-explorer.net/kernel/kptr_restrict/